# Date time parse or time class?

Tags: ruby, parsing, date, time

This is for Ruby

Need help understanding Time.parse.  I want the output to be "2011-01-02 11:00:00"

but I am getting "2011-01-02 11:00:00 -0800" with the following code.  Any ideas?

```
require 'time'

def measure

    Time.parse("2011-1-2 11:00:00")
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just printing the number of hours your timezone is off UTC. You can use [`Time#strftime`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Time.html#method-i-strftime) to extract only the fields you are interested in

```
def measure
   t = Time.parse("2011-1-2 11:00:00")

   t.strftime "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
end

# irb(main):037:0> measure
# => "2011-01-02 11:00:00"
```